# How to list newly ftp added HTML webpage under Pages section of wp-admin?

Tags: wp-admin, static-website, file-manager

I uploaded a custom page (html,css, and a few scripts) through the file manager, and want the customer to have access to this page through the admin "Pages" menu in the admin area.

The page is accessible through

```
www.site.com/{my_page}
```

but admin area doesn't recognize it under **Pages**.

How should I put it under Pages section of admin area?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please accept and upvote if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your newly uploaded page through ftp.

## 1. Static content

If your have static content:

1. Go to Admin area and go to **Pages** section and add a new page. You may change the slug to `my_page` or any thing else (it should be an available slug and not already assigned to any other post or page)
2. Put your content inside the **Editor** section and use TinyMCE to make it look as your want. You may use h1-h6, **Bold**, *Italic*, put images and videos and more.

## 2. Dynamic content

If your have dynamic content needs:

### 2.1. You own the current theme

If you own the theme you may add your file to your theme:

1. Create a file named `page-{slug}.php` under your theme's root directory where `{slug}` is your page slug (maybe `my_page` which will be `page-my_page.php`) and you may access it like:

   ```
   www.site.com/my_page
   ```
2. put some inclusions to include common parts like header & footer into it:

   ```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <main>
       <?php
       if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
           while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
               <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
               <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
           <?php
           endwhile;
       endif;
       ?>
   </main>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```

### 2.2. You use a default wordpress (2020 theme) or any 3rd party theme

If you do not own the theme, then you may consider creating a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and go to step 2.1 afterwards.